# How to handle production and R&D versions for backend

Tags: database, postgresql, backend

I'm currently working on an application that requires both a production and R&D version of the app. Currently I'm using two separate databases.

But I was wondering: Would it be a better to simply have a column in the data "IsRD" to determine if the data was for the RD version, all within the same database?

Comment: no, the systems must always be separated, as production can loose data, through an error you make in programming and then you need to restore tehbakupad have maybe lost data

Comment: No! For security purposes developers should NOT access production. I've seen so many cases where the developers forgets the WHERE clause in a DELETE statement... and end up deleting all the production data.